# multiple threads issue in visual studio debugging

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

Environment:  Win7 Pro, VS2013 Ultimate, asp.net website (not application), vb.net

(This is a major edit that focuses more on the problem as currently understood. Looks at this point like it might be a user-code specific issue.)

Almost complete resolution, 3/1 4:15 pm PDT:  If I get rid of the nasty loop in the code, by just counting and quitting when the counter gets too high, the problem seems to go away entirely, including not leaving IISExpress with high CPU usage.  Still don't know why, but maybe that's just another unexplainable IDE anomaly.  Probably doesn't need any more attention.

The basic problem is breakpoints not getting hit during debug runs, and the "the process or thread has changed since last step" condition.  It seems directly related to IISExpress.

If I go into task manager and kill IISExpress between debug runs, it doesn't have the problem with the breakpoints.  I've tested that three times and is consistent.

Plus IISExpress shows 25-50% CPU usage.

The problem started out of nowhere a couple of days ago on VS2013 Premium.  I had been testing essentially the same code for several weeks with no issue.  I reinstalled Ultimate with SP4 to see if that would make a difference, however, not so.

The current code set that I'm testing does have a nasty loop in it that I'm trying to remove, however, if I step through the loop just a few times and then kill the debug I still get the problem.

I have another website on the same system that I'm testing that does not exhibit this problem and does not leave iisexpress with the high CPU usage between debug.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET async features? Or are you just starting regular threads?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm enough of a newbie that I'm not sure what that means.  I'm not running the website in VS2013 pretty much "vanilla", with no particular settings with respect to ASP.NET async that I'm aware of.  Is there a way to check for that?  Also, part of the problem is related to IISExpress.  If I go into task manager and kill IISExpress between debug runs, it doesn't have the problem with the breakpoints.  I've tested that three times and is consistent.  Plus IISExpress shows 25-50% CPU usage...something goofy there.

Comment: I mean, are you using `Task` class or `ThreadStart` or something like that?

Comment: No, not using either of those.